# Why the largest contour isn't detected using OpenCv?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, android

I'm currently developing an android application using OpenCv and the first step of the process is to detect and extract the largest contour of an image from the camera.

I applied Canny edge detector and findContours() function but it's not working correctly and the real contour is never detected.
I tried to play with Canny and thresholding parameters and tried removing image binarization without any luck.

Here is the original image : 
        [image: https://i.imgur.com/gGYuDmy.png]

and here is the result : 
        [image: https://i.imgur.com/NxVx8Ru.png]

The java code to detect and draw contour:

```
    private Mat findLargestRectangle_2(Mat original_image) {
    imgSource = new Mat(original_image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    //imgSource = original_image;

    //convert the image to black and white
    Imgproc.cvtColor(original_image, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Imgproc.equalizeHist(imgSource, imgSource);

    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imgSource, imgSource, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 40);

    //apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 1);

    //convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
    Imgproc.Canny(imgSource, imgSource, 100, 200, 3, false);

    //find the contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    double maxArea = -1;
    int maxAreaIdx = -1;

    if (contours.size() > 0) {
        MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); //the largest is at the index 0 for starting point
        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        Mat largest_contour = contours.get(0);
        MatOfPoint2f maxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        List<MatOfPoint> largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
            temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
            double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
            //compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
            if (contourarea > maxArea) {
                //check if this contour is a square
                MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( temp_contour.toArray() );
                int contourSize = (int)temp_contour.total();
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve, contourSize*0.05, true);
                if (approxCurve.total() == 4) {
                    maxArea = contourarea;
                    maxCurve = approxCurve;
                    maxAreaIdx = idx;
                    largest_contours.add(temp_contour);
                    largest_contour = temp_contour;
                }
            }
        }

        if (largest_contours.size() >= 1) {
            MatOfPoint temp_largest = largest_contours.get(largest_contours.size()-1);
            largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            largest_contours.add(temp_largest);
        }

        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
        Imgproc.drawContours(imgSource, largest_contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);

        double temp_double[] = maxCurve.get(0, 0);
        if(temp_double != null) {
            Point p1 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
            Imgproc.circle(imgSource, new Point(p1.x, p1.y), 20, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 5); //p1 is colored red
        }

        temp_double = maxCurve.get(1, 0);

        if(temp_double != null) {

            Point p2 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
            Imgproc.circle(imgSource, new Point(p2.x, p2.y), 20, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 5); //p2 is colored green
        }

        temp_double = maxCurve.get(2, 0);

        if(temp_double != null) {
            Point p3 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
            Imgproc.circle(imgSource, new Point(p3.x, p3.y), 20, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 5); //p3 is colored blue
        }

        temp_double = maxCurve.get(3, 0);

        if(temp_double != null) {
            Point p4 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
            Imgproc.circle(imgSource, new Point(p4.x, p4.y), 20, new Scalar(0, 255, 255), 5); //p1 is colored violet
        }
    }

    return imgSource;
}
```

I'm stuck in this process for several days now and I wish you guys can help me figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You do like 100 things to imgSource and then you do `Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);` ???? that does not make sense, maybe it is from GRAY? Canny gives a lot of broken edges, which maybe you have to play with the parameters to get the edges of a complete square... as it is now it looks like it got you the biggest line defined by 4 points. You should first get edges or the object per se visible, then do the contour stuff. I would suggest to use line detector rather than your approach.

Comment: @api55 Thank you for your answer. As I understand, you suggest using something like HoughLines ? . Can you give me a better explanation please?

Comment: Try removing the adaptive threshold. Canny needs to be applied to the original grey-value image. By thresholding you are throwing away all sorts of relevant edges and details. The histogram equalization should probably also go away. Just apply Canny to the original, grey-value image.

Comment: Good suggestion , I removed adaptive threshold and gaussian blur and changed Canny parameters to 170,200. The good news it started detecting the largest contour but this contour keeps changing .It's like detection isn't stable .What do you suggest sir?